# Which report does the SendEvent data appear on in the Google Analytics dashboard?

Tags: android, google-analytics

Which report does the SendEvent data appear on in the Google Analytics dashboard?
Here is my Android code :

```
myTracker.sendEvent("Button", "Share Button", "ArticleDisplay",LgoolgeAnalytics);
```

Logcat:

```
 07-23 20:35:53.509: I/GAV2(8352): Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to store
```

Where can I see the sendEvent's on the dashboard?

Steve

Comment: Have you checked the Event reports under Content>Events ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Event Report, wheren in as per the method signature 
`myTracker.sendEvent(String category, String action, String label, int value);`

`myTracker.sendEvent("Button", "Share Button", "ArticleDisplay",LgoolgeAnalytics);`

In `Google-Analytics` if you want to see the reprots, its under `Behviour > Events > Overview`